# iOS Swift 3: Importing AVFoundation produced unwanted underlined button text

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, avfoundation

After adding `import AVFoundation` to my project, all of my button's text in the entire app became underlined (which is unwanted). I was wondering why this happened and what can be done to fix it. Additionally, the selected tab in my tab bar is now highlighted with blue.

**Update:** I was unable to produce the problem when running the app in the simulator, it only seems to persist on my physical device.

**Update 2:** After creating a new project, adding a single button, and importing `AVFoundation`, the problem still persisted. Screenshot and code below

**Update 3 -with solution-** After uninstalling my original app, the button in the new app is no longer underlined.. I was following a tutorial in which i was instructed to add to "Link Binary With Libraries" (Project -> Build Phases). After removing AVFoundation.Framework and AVKit.framework my app appears to be working as expected

**ViewController.swift:**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  AVFoundationTest
//
//  Created by justin frazer on 2/19/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 jfrazer. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What makes you think AVFoundation is guilty? It's an old framework used in a lot of apps, it can't be the cause.

Comment: because after commenting out the import line, the text was no longer underlined

Comment: that's really interesting, have you tried it on clean project?

Comment: Just tried cleaning it to no avail >.< - also see the update

Comment: well, I mean, what If you create entirely new project and try to do the same there?

Comment: and btw what iOS version installed on your device?

Comment: currently running 10.2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136093/discussion-between-fyodor-volchyok-and-justin-frazer).

Comment: @JustinFrazer The question is. Did you try to create a completely new project and add an UIButton and AVFoundation and reproduce the error? If no, try it, and see how it does not happen in a new project. So , provide code to your simple UIViewController where it happens. And a **screenshot** of the visual error .

Comment: After creating a brand new project, adding a single button, and importing AVFoundation, the button's text was still underlined in the app (which i did not set in the storyboard) - screenshot & code coming soon

Comment: please take a look at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136093/discussion-between-fyodor-volchyok-and-justin-frazer

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the connection to the `AVFoundation` import either but I'm pretty sure that the option "**Button Shapes**" is enabled in your device's **Accessibility settings**. It's a feature that helps users recognize tappable buttons by underlining their title (regular buttons) or giving them a particular shape and background color (navigation and toolbar buttons).

You can deactivate this setting on your device here:

**Settings** ❯ **General** ❯ **Accessibility** ❯ **Button Shapes**

Just switch that option off and your app's buttons should return to their normal appearance.

Comment: The toggle has been off since the beginning =/

Comment: Curious. Have you checked if other apps on the same device show the same behavior or is it _only_ your app? (In particular, open the App Store on your device and check if the tab bar shows the same highlight as your app does.)

Comment: Check out my update 3; after removing two frameworks the app began working as expected (although i have no idea why these frameworks were the problem)

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from adding two frameworks as instructed in a tutorial i was following (AVKit.framework & AVFoundation.framework in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries). This caused **all** of my apps to behave different. After removing these frameworks the underlined text and highlighted/selected tab bar went away